Clusters con Replicacion y Distribucion de Clickhouse - Replicacion con Keeper
Necesito crear la replicación en clickhouse; en dos máquinas diferentes que están bajo la misma red. He intentado configurarlo pero me sale el siguiente error:
SQL Error [999] [07000]: Code: 999. Coordination::Exception: All connection tries failed while connecting to ZooKeeper. do not give
Tengo configurado en el server 1 y server 2, las instancias de clickhouse que deberian conectarse entre si mediante la replica, he levantado las configuraciones pero al crear la tabla replicada me muestra el error anteriormente mencionado.
Server 1: 192.168.101.105 docker-compose.yml
version: '3.8'

services:
  clickhouse_demo:
    image: yandex/clickhouse-server:latest
    container_name: clickhouse-demo
    hostname: clickhouse-demo
    environment:
      - CLICKHOUSE_CONFIG=/etc/clickhouse-server/config.xml
      - CLICKHOUSE_PASSWORD=tecate.01
    volumes:
      - ./clickhouse_demo/config.xml:/etc/clickhouse-server/config.xml
      - - ./clickhouse_node/data:/var/lib/clickhouse'
    mem_limit: 32g
    cpus: "6"
    ports:
      - "8123:8123"
      - "9000:9000"
    depends_on:
      - clickhouse-keeper-demo
  clickhouse-keeper-demo:
    image: clickhouse/clickhouse-keeper:latest
    container_name: clickhouse-keeper-demo
    hostname: clickhouse-keeper-demo
    volumes:
     - ./clickhouse_keeper_demo/clickhouse-keeper/keeper_config.xml:/etc/clickhouse-keeper/keeper_config.xml
    ports:
        - "9181:9181"

config.xml
<remote_servers>
        <my_cluster>
            <shard>
                <internal_replication>true</internal_replication>
                <replica>
                    <host>192.168.101.105</host>
                    <port>9000</port>
                    <user>default</user>
                    <password>tecate.01</password>
                </replica>
            </shard>
            <shard>
                <replica>
                    <host>192.168.101.104</host>
                    <port>9000</port>
                    <user>default</user>
                    <password>tecate.01</password>
                </replica>
            </shard>
        </my_cluster>
    
    <zookeeper>
        <node>
            <host>192.168.101.105</host>
            <port>9181</port>
        </node>
        <node>
            <host>192.168.101.105</host>
            <port>9181</port>
        </node>
    </zookeeper>
<macros>
        <shard>01</shard>
        <replica>01</replica>
        <cluster>my_cluster</cluster>
    </macros>

keeper.xml
<clickhouse replace="true">
    <logger>
        <level>information</level>
        <log>/var/log/clickhouse-keeper/clickhouse-keeper.log</log>
        <errorlog>/var/log/clickhouse-keeper/clickhouse-keeper.err.log</errorlog>
        <size>1000M</size>
        <count>3</count>
    </logger>
    <listen_host>0.0.0.0</listen_host>
    <keeper_server>
        <tcp_port>9181</tcp_port>
        <server_id>1</server_id>
        <log_storage_path>/var/lib/clickhouse/coordination/log</log_storage_path>
        <snapshot_storage_path>/var/lib/clickhouse/coordination/snapshots</snapshot_storage_path>
        <coordination_settings>
            <operation_timeout_ms>10000</operation_timeout_ms>
            <session_timeout_ms>30000</session_timeout_ms>
            <raft_logs_level>information</raft_logs_level>
        </coordination_settings>
        <raft_configuration>
            <server>
                <id>1</id>
                <hostname>192.168.101.105</hostname>
                <port>8444</port>
            </server>
            <server>
                <id>2</id>
                <hostname>192.168.101.104</hostname>
                <port>8444</port>
            </server>
        </raft_configuration>
    </keeper_server>
</clickhouse>

Server 2: 192.168.101.104 docker-compose.yml
version: '3.8'

services:
  clickhouse_node:
    image: yandex/clickhouse-server:latest
    container_name: clickhouse-node
    hostname: clickhouse-node
    environment:
      - CLICKHOUSE_CONFIG=/etc/clickhouse-server/config.xml
      - CLICKHOUSE_PASSWORD=tecate.01
    volumes:
      - ./clickhouse_node/config.xml:/etc/clickhouse-server/config.xml
      - ./clickhouse_node/data:/var/lib/clickhouse
    mem_limit: 32g
    cpus: "6"
    ports:
      - "8123:8123"
      - "9000:9000"
    depends_on:
      - clickhouse-keeper-node
  clickhouse-keeper-node:
    image: clickhouse/clickhouse-keeper:latest
    container_name: clickhouse-keeper-node
    hostname: clickhouse-keeper-node
    volumes:
     - ./clickhouse_keeper_node/clickhouse-keeper/keeper_config.xml:/etc/clickhouse-keeper/keeper_config.xml
    ports:
        - "9181:9181"

config.xml
<remote_servers>
        <my_cluster>
            <shard>
                <internal_replication>true</internal_replication>
                <replica>
                    <host>192.168.101.105</host>
                    <port>9000</port>
                    <user>default</user>
                    <password>tecate.01</password>
                </replica>
            </shard>
            <shard>
                <replica>
                    <host>192.168.101.104</host>
                    <port>9000</port>
                    <user>default</user>
                    <password>tecate.01</password>
                </replica>
            </shard>
        </my_cluster>
    
    <zookeeper>
        <node>
            <host>192.168.101.105</host>
            <port>9181</port>
        </node>
        <node>
            <host>192.168.101.105</host>
            <port>9181</port>
        </node>
    </zookeeper>
<macros>
        <shard>01</shard>
        <replica>02</replica>
        <cluster>my_cluster</cluster>
    </macros>

keeper.xml
<clickhouse replace="true">
    <logger>
        <level>information</level>
        <log>/var/log/clickhouse-keeper/clickhouse-keeper.log</log>
        <errorlog>/var/log/clickhouse-keeper/clickhouse-keeper.err.log</errorlog>
        <size>1000M</size>
        <count>3</count>
    </logger>
    <listen_host>0.0.0.0</listen_host>
    <keeper_server>
        <tcp_port>9181</tcp_port>
        <server_id>2</server_id>
        <log_storage_path>/var/lib/clickhouse/coordination/log</log_storage_path>
        <snapshot_storage_path>/var/lib/clickhouse/coordination/snapshots</snapshot_storage_path>
        <coordination_settings>
            <operation_timeout_ms>10000</operation_timeout_ms>
            <session_timeout_ms>30000</session_timeout_ms>
            <raft_logs_level>information</raft_logs_level>
        </coordination_settings>
        <raft_configuration>
            <server>
                <id>1</id>
                <hostname>192.168.101.105</hostname>
                <port>8444</port>
            </server>
            <server>
                <id>2</id>
                <hostname>192.168.101.104</hostname>
                <port>8444</port>
            </server>
        </raft_configuration>
    </keeper_server>
</clickhouse>

